# Get source Ip and port - NAT

Tags: iptables, vpn, nat

I routed all my traffic through my code .
I used Iptables in Linux to forward all requests which requested 53 port with this command :

```
iptables -t nat -p udp -A OUTPUT -j DNAT --dport 53 --to-destination 127.0.0.1:3400
```

My code only received a requested query . There is no source Ip and Port number
Then how can I realize the source Ip and Port number ?
How VPN connections are working ? Is there using NAT too ?

Comment: This is a delete statement (`-D`), are you sure about the statement? What do you mean by `There is no source Ip and Port number`? Where there is no ip and port? How did you check? How VPN connections are working is a very large topic, do you have specific questions? `Is there using NAT too?` Is where nat too?

Comment: Mistake . i meant Append in Iptables. I wonder about how can realize about souce ip and port because in my code I only can read source as ip and port which i used in as a destination in iptables rules.